# How to filter out the unique combinations from a list of subsets

Tags: python, arrays, list, subset

I was trying come up with a script to to implement [Subset sum Prob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), with some help from the first script of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum). So, now running my script, I get this:

```
maci:python sant$ ./subsetSum.py -n3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5 -t12
[3, 4, 5] => 12
[3, 4, 5] => 12
[3, 5, 4] => 12
[3, 6, 3] => 12
[3, 9] => 12
[3, 4, 5] => 12
[4, 5, 3] => 12
[4, 8] => 12
[4, 3, 5] => 12
[5, 7] => 12
[5, 3, 4] => 12
[7, 5] => 12
[8, 4] => 12
[9, 3] => 12
[3, 4, 5] => 12
```

Which is working just fine. But how do I filter out only the unique subset? In the result, 1, 2 and 15 are exactly the same and there are other 6, which are the combination of [3,4,5]. How do I print only one in stead of all of them? cheers!!

PS. I know that the Q is probably not reflecting what actually I want, so feel free to improve it.

Comment: \*poke\* Forgetting something? Source code? ...

Comment: Didn't bother to add the code as the "effective" part of code is identical to the first script of the post, which I mentioned in my OP. Besides, I thought it ne will taken as a simple conversion from this: `[[3, 4, 5], [4, 3, 5], [5, 3, 4], [3, 6], [6,3]]` to `[[3, 4, 5], [3, 6]]`. But I do agree a bit of source code is always good. Sorry about that. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having numbers in your list multiple times just add tuples of (number, multiplicity)
so your input would become `[(3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]`.

This makes it easy to create your subsets without duplicates. You could do somethings like:

```
for i in n[1]:
    subset_sum_recursive(remaining, target, partial + i * [n[0]])
```

Alternatively it might be easier to keep not only your "partial" list but also a "discarded" list. Then you can check

```
if(n not in discarded)
    subset_sum_recursive(remaining,target,partial + [n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tuples (which are immutable) instead of lists. Then you can convert the list of them to a set (which removes duplicates) and finally convert the set back to a list.

ie `list(set([(3,4,5),(3,4,5),(3,5,4),(3,6,3) ...]))` produces `[(3,4,5),(3,5,4),(3,6,3) ...]`

You can use map to convert the items to and from tuples:

```
map(tuple, your list of lists)
```

and

```
map(list, your list of tuples)
```